# Unmarshalling nested objects using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I am using JAXB and can't figure out why my nested objects aren't being unmarshalled. I am generating the classes via the XJC command.

For example, when I unmarshall the Works object, the Composers collection always contains one Composer instance will a NULL name.

My XML looks like this:

```
<Works>
    <Work>
        <Composer>
           <Name>Test Name</Name>
        </Composer>
    </Work>
</Works>
```

and XSD is like this:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jxb:version="2.0" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test/"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/"> 

<element name="Works" type="tns:Work"></element>

<complexType name="Work">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Composers" type="tns:Composer" maxOccurs="unbounded"
            minOccurs="1">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>


<complexType name="Composer">
    <sequence>
        <element name="Name" type="string">
        </element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

And my code that does the unmarshalling:

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("mypackagename");
    Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    Works works = (Works)um.unmarshal(new FileReader("src/main/resources/works.xml"));
    Work work = works.getWorks().get(0);
    Composer composer = work.getComposers().get(0);
    System.out.println(composer.getName());
```

Name is always NULL, even though I know it has a value.

Comment: I think that the xml instance, should be `<Works><Composers><Name>Test</Name></Composers></Works>` per xsd and not like the one you mention

Comment: Sorry, slight typo on my part, when I retrieve the composer it would be work.getComposers() not works.getComposer() - I have amended the code.

Comment: @seedhead - You have defined the `Works` element to be of type `Work`, not to contain element `Work`.

Comment: So I need to do something like this? 

    <element name="Works" type="tns:WorkListType"></element>

Comment: @seedhead - I have added a schema you could use as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have an XML schema like:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jxb:version="2.0" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/test/"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/test/">

    <element name="Works" type="tns:Works"></element>

    <complexType name="Works">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Work" type="tns:Work" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="Work">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Composer" type="tns:Composer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>


    <complexType name="Composer">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Name" type="string"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

</schema>
```

That corresponds to the following XML:

```
<Works xmlns="http://www.example.org/test/">
    <Work>
        <Composer>
           <Name>Test Name</Name>
        </Composer>
    </Work>
</Works>
```

Comment: in your above example schema, shouldn't it be  <element name="Works" type="tns:Works"></element> not  <element name="Works" type="tns:Work"></element>?

Comment: @seedhead - You are correct, I have made the change to the XML schema.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your xsd and now I get this problem when unmarshalling: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.org/test/", local:"Works"). Expected elements are (none)

Comment: When I try adding the @XmlRootElement annotation to the Works class I get a slightly different error: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.example.org/test/", local:"Work"). Expected elements are <{}Works>